# Creating permutation via recursive CTE in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, recursion, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

Looking at  :

```
;WITH cte AS(
    SELECT 1 AS x UNION
    SELECT 2 AS x UNION     
    SELECT 3 AS x   
)
```

I can create permutation table  for all 3 values :

```
SELECT T1.x , y=T2.x , z=t3.x
FROM cte T1
JOIN cte T2
ON T1.x != T2.x
JOIN cte T3
ON T2.x != T3.x AND T1.x != T3.x
```

This uses the power of SQL's cartesian product plus  eliminating equal values.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1nnZ.png]

OK.

But is it possible to enhance this recursive pseudo CTE :

```
;WITH cte AS(
    SELECT 1 AS x ,  2 AS y , 3 AS z   
    UNION ALL 
    ...
)

SELECT * FROM cte
```

[image]

So that it will yield same result as  :

[image]

*NB there are other solutions in SO that uses recursive CTE , but it is not spread to columns , but string representation of the permutations*

Comment: With just one row of data?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Yes . this is the seed.

Comment: For 3 elements it can be done relatively easily but its specific to 3 elements. Do you just need the 3 element one or are you looking for a solution that scales out?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes. sorry for not mehtion that. I want to be able to declare `;WITH cte AS(
    SELECT 1 AS x ,     SELECT 2 AS y ,... SELECT n as N.. 
)`  - and it to be dynamic. If I supply the containers columns - the CTE shhould be able to fill them

Comment: Why are you trying to use a recursive cte to do something that is simple to do with simple joins?

Comment: This is not what a Recursive CTE is about. Recursive CTE is about constructing a hierarchy of rows that point to parent rows in the same table. This is a simple theta join between two tables. Also to make any dynamic result set with a different number of columns can only be done using dynamic SQL where you build a string and EXEC(@sql). That is because SQL binds the column names and types at the compilation stage when it checks syntax and not dynamically at runtime after it's executed the code.

Comment: Maybe create a CLR function that makes a call out to http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=permutations+of+%7B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%7D and then parses the HTML output? If you want to use it in a recursive CTE, then call out to it twice and double check your result :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to do the lot in a CTE.

However trying to "redefine" a rowset dynamically is a little tricky.  While the task is relatively easy using dynamic SQL doing it without poses some issues.

While this answer may not be the most efficient or straight forward, or even correct in the sense that it's not all CTE it may give others a basis to work from.

To best understand my approach read the comments, but it might be worthwhile looking at each CTE expression in turn with by altering the bit of code below in the main block, with commenting out the section below it.

```
SELECT * FROM <CTE NAME>
```

Good luck.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#cteSchema') IS NOT NULL
    DROP Table #cteSchema
GO

-- BASE CTE
;WITH cte AS( SELECT 1 AS x, 2 AS y, 3 AS z),

    -- So we know what columns we have from the CTE we extract it to XML
    Xml_Schema AS ( SELECT CONVERT(XML,(SELECT * FROM cte FOR XML PATH(''))) AS MySchema ),

    -- Next we need to get a list of the columns from the CTE, by querying the XML, getting the values and assigning a num to the column
    MyColumns AS (SELECT D.ROWS.value('fn:local-name(.)','SYSNAME') AS ColumnName,
                        D.ROWS.value('.','SYSNAME') as Value,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY D.ROWS.value('fn:local-name(.)','SYSNAME')) AS Num
                    FROM Xml_Schema
                        CROSS APPLY Xml_Schema.MySchema.nodes('/*') AS D(ROWS) ),
    -- How many columns we have in the CTE, used a coupld of times below
    ColumnStats AS (SELECT MAX(NUM) AS ColumnCount FROM MyColumns),

    -- create a cartesian product of the column names and values, so now we get each column with it's possible values,
    -- so {x=1, x =2, x=3, y=1, y=2, y=3, z=1, z=2, z=3} -- you get the idea.
    PossibleValues AS (SELECT MyC.ColumnName, MyC.Num AS ColumnNum, MyColumns.Value, MyColumns.Num, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MyC.ColumnName, MyColumns.Value, MyColumns.Num ) AS ID
                FROM MyColumns 
                    CROSS APPLY MyColumns MyC
                ),

    -- Now we have the possibly values of each "column" we now have to concat the values together using this recursive CTE.
    AllRawXmlRows AS (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),'<'+ISNULL((SELECT ColumnName FROM MyColumns WHERE MyColumns.Num = 1),'')+'>'+Value) as ConcatedValue, Value,ID, Counterer = 1  FROM PossibleValues
                UNION ALL
            SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), AllRawXmlRows.ConcatedValue)+'</'+(SELECT ColumnName FROM MyColumns WHERE MyColumns.Num = Counterer)+'><'+(SELECT ColumnName FROM MyColumns WHERE MyColumns.Num = Counterer+1)+'>'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),PossibleValues.Value))  AS ConcatedValue, PossibleValues.Value, PossibleValues.ID,
            Counterer = Counterer+1
            FROM AllRawXmlRows
                INNER JOIN PossibleValues  ON AllRawXmlRows.ConcatedValue NOT LIKE '%'+PossibleValues.Value+'%' -- I hate this, there has to be a better way of making sure we don't duplicate values.... 
                AND AllRawXmlRows.ID <> PossibleValues.ID
                AND Counterer < (SELECT ColumnStats.ColumnCount FROM ColumnStats)
                ),

    -- The above made a list but was missing the final closing XML element. so we add it.
    -- we also restict the list to the items that contain all columns, the section above builds it up over many columns
    XmlRows AS (SELECT DISTINCT 
                ConcatedValue +'</'+(SELECT ColumnName FROM MyColumns WHERE MyColumns.Num = Counterer)+'>' 
                AS ConcatedValue
            FROM AllRawXmlRows WHERE Counterer = (SELECT ColumnStats.ColumnCount FROM ColumnStats)
                    ),              
    -- Wrap the output in row and table tags to create the final XML
    FinalXML AS (SELECT (SELECT CONVERT(XML,(SELECT CONVERT(XML,ConcatedValue) FROM XmlRows FOR XML PATH('row'))) FOR XML PATH('table') )as XMLData),

    -- Prepare a CTE that represents the structure of the original CTE with 
    DataTable AS (SELECT cte.*, XmlData
                        FROM FinalXML, cte)
--SELECT * FROM <CTE NAME>
    -- GETS destination columns with XML data.
SELECT * 
    INTO #cteSchema
FROM DataTable


DECLARE @XML VARCHAR(MAX) ='';
SELECT @Xml = XMLData FROM #cteSchema --Extract XML Data from the

ALTER TABLE #cteSchema DROP Column XMLData -- Removes the superflous column
DECLARE @h INT
EXECUTE sp_xml_preparedocument @h OUTPUT, @XML
    SELECT * 
        FROM OPENXML(@h, '/table/row', 2) 
            WITH #cteSchema -- just use the #cteSchema to define the structure of the xml that has been constructed

EXECUTE sp_xml_removedocument @h
```

Comment: You got my vote but for five columns it took 2:40 min.

Comment: Yeah, it's not very efficient, but it's also not the right approach to the problem. Dynamic SQL would be a much simpler and efficient method. Thanks for the vote though. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about translating 1,2,3 into a column, which will look exactly like the example you started from, and use the same approach ?

```
;WITH origin (x,y,z) AS (
    SELECT 1,2,3
), translated (x) AS ( 
    SELECT  col
    FROM    origin
            UNPIVOT ( col FOR cols IN (x,y,z)) AS up
)
SELECT T1.x , y=T2.x , z=t3.x
FROM    translated T1
        JOIN translated T2
            ON T1.x != T2.x
        JOIN translated T3
            ON T2.x != T3.x AND T1.x != T3.x
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

If I understood correctly the request, this might just do the trick.

And to run it on more columns, just need to add them origin cte definition + unpivot column list.

Now, i dont know how you pass your 1 - n values for it to be dynamic, but if you tell me, i could try edit the script to be dynamic too.